# How to move packages from a build machine into a SDK/cross compiler tool chain

Tags: sdk, cross-platform, cross-compiling, ubuntu-18.04

I am aiming to build an sdk targeting 32bit debian8 platform. And would like to move few packages likes cmake, maven, scons etc on to the sdk. These packages helps to compile the code (cmake, scons etc) but doesn't actually present/needed on the robot.

Rather than compiling these pkgs, I was advised to fetch the pre-build packages/binaries and all their dependencies from the build system (here build system = host system = ubuntu18.04 ) and place them in SDK folder.

How can I point all the sysloader files to load them from the local SDK. Thus making it self contained ?

Not sure, if this works or at-least hard to make it work ? Is this the right way of doing it ?

Can you guys shed some light on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the packages to the desired location and used [patchelf](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf). I have observed that [Home brew on linux](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux) is also performing the patching (brew install  -v)